# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views,inline functions,derived tables,subqueries,and common table expressions,unless TOP,OFFSET or FOR XML is

Tags: sql, sql-server

My `UPDATE` statement here:

```
Update S 
set Status = 6 
Where Status = 5 
  and P_ID in (1, 3) 
  and ID in (Select dbo.T.sID 
             from dbo.T  
             Group By s 
             having Max(TDate) <= @t1 and Max(TDate) >= @t2 
                and sid is not null
             order by Max(TDate))
```

results in an error being shown:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Is there a question here? It seems pretty straight-forward, especially considering you don't need an order by here...

Answer (score 0):

`order by` clause meaningless for inline queries. Just delete `order by Max(TDate)` part from your query.

```
Update S 
set Status = 6 
Where Status = 5 
  and P_ID in (1, 3) 
  and ID in (Select dbo.T.sID 
             from dbo.T  
             Group By s 
             having Max(TDate) <= @t1 and Max(TDate) >= @t2 
                and sid is not null )
```